Can't configure my Onion resource
I have Ubuntu Server 24.04 installed on my virtual machine (Oracle Virtual Box). Apache 2 web server with a single website on it, without virtual hosts. I want to make my website an onion resource and for this I installed Tor.
sudo apt-get install tor

After that I went to /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/hostname and looked at my onion address.
When I go to my address in the Tor browser, I get the message: "Onion site not found
The most likely reason is that the onion website is offline. Contact the onion site administrator."
Just two lines of settings
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80

I have no idea where to look for the error. Please tell me what could be wrong?

It turned out that in my country Tor has been blocked since 2022 and connecting without bridges is impossible.
Installing bridges:
sudo apt install obfs4proxy

Now you need to get a list of bridges/bridges:
https://bridges.torproject.org/bridges/?transport=obfs4
Add to the end /etc/tor/torrc :
ClientTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy
Bridge obfs4 IPADDRESS:PORT 0F14...
UseBridges 1 

Please note that Bridge must be added to each copied line.
The bridges are now configured and working. But I still can't connect. And I have no ideas. If there is a knowledgeable person here, please tell me what to do.
Oct 26 17:40:27.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0% (starting): Starting
Oct 26 17:40:27.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "bridges"
Oct 26 17:40:27.000 [notice] Delaying directory fetches: No running bridges
Oct 26 17:40:28.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 1% (conn_pt): Connecting to pluggable transport
Oct 26 17:40:28.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 2% (conn_done_pt): Connected to pluggable transport
Oct 26 17:40:28.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [XX::1]:1110 ID=<none> RSA_ID=XYZ ("general SOCKS server failure")


sudo chown tor -R /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/ and sudo chmod 700 -R /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/ - didn't help.

Oct 26 14:21:17.498 [notice] Tor 0.4.8.10 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.12-stable, OpenSSL 3.0.13, Zlib 1.3, Liblzma 5.4.5, Libzstd 1.5.5 and Glibc 2.39 as libc.
Oct 26 14:21:17.498 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://support.torproject.org/faq/staying-anonymous/
Oct 26 14:21:17.498 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Oct 26 14:21:17.500 [warn] Directory /var/lib/tor/hidden_service/ cannot be read: Permission denied

Oct 26 14:21:17.500 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to configure rendezvous options. See logs for details.
Oct 26 14:21:17.500 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.

This folder is empty /var/log/tor

Well, your experiments are making sense. However - some tips: add the data to your question body, not as answers. But it's OK - you've provided enough data to answer your question. Yes, in Debian and Ubuntu installations of Tor there is a bug that fires up from time to time with permissions for it's folder - that's why your reinstall has helped you. The last log is where you have the config without a bridges - reinstall kills your old config. SSL state deaths - are about the DPI and SSL intrusions. Public bridges service is good and can totally save your day, but it's not a silver bullet. You have to make your very own bridges without publishing them - state it in your config!! After that - use either obfs4 with a key/pass, or check out the STunnel and Shadowsocks - they are good for DPI penetration. Also keep in mind that Yggdrasil and I2P can be a good transport for Tor's bridges of your own. The Debian setup is actually a clever one - it allows you to have multiple Tor instances running on the same OS without interfering to each other. So use one instance to reach the Tor network - and a separate instance to run your hidden service and patch it through a local connection to your first one. It will work.

It turned out that in my country Tor has been blocked since 2022 and connecting without bridges is impossible.
Installing bridges:
sudo apt install obfs4proxy

Now you need to get a list of bridges/bridges:
https://bridges.torproject.org/bridges/?transport=obfs4
Add to the end /etc/tor/torrc :
ClientTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy
Bridge obfs4 185.246.188.76:7180 0F14...
Bridge obfs4 208.87.97.172:1701 08AA...
Bridge obfs4 54.196.245.125:9162 7966...
UseBridges 1 

Please note that Bridge must be added to each copied line.
The bridges are now configured and working. But I still can't connect. And I have no ideas. If there is a knowledgeable person here, please tell me what to do.
Oct 26 17:40:27.520 [notice] Tor 0.4.8.10 running on Linux with Libevent 2.1.12-stable, OpenSSL 3.0.13, Zlib 1.3, Liblzma 5.4.5, Libzstd 1.5.5 and Glibc 2.39 as libc.
Oct 26 17:40:27.520 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://support.torproject.org/faq/staying-anonymous/
Oct 26 17:40:27.520 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Oct 26 17:40:27.524 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Oct 26 17:40:27.524 [notice] Opened Socks listener connection (ready) on 127.0.0.1:9050
Oct 26 17:40:27.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv4 file /usr/share/tor/geoip.
Oct 26 17:40:27.000 [notice] Parsing GEOIP IPv6 file /usr/share/tor/geoip6.
Oct 26 17:40:27.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 0% (starting): Starting
Oct 26 17:40:27.000 [notice] Starting with guard context "bridges"
Oct 26 17:40:27.000 [notice] Delaying directory fetches: No running bridges
Oct 26 17:40:28.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 1% (conn_pt): Connecting to pluggable transport
Oct 26 17:40:28.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 2% (conn_done_pt): Connected to pluggable transport
Oct 26 17:40:28.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2a01:4f8:c012:da96::1]:1110 ID=<none> RSA_ID=8FB7B23A1D5DC1C0292C3EE6974FB4FD04CE4B3F ("general SOCKS server failure")
Oct 26 17:40:28.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2605:6400:30:f174:42::]:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=503EB70C30120C72988B47087C720B582B6AB135 ("general SOCKS server failure")
Oct 26 17:40:29.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2605:6400:30:f174:42::]:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=503EB70C30120C72988B47087C720B582B6AB135 ("general SOCKS server failure")
Oct 26 17:40:29.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2a01:4f8:c012:da96::1]:1110 ID=<none> RSA_ID=8FB7B23A1D5DC1C0292C3EE6974FB4FD04CE4B3F ("general SOCKS server failure")
Oct 26 17:40:30.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2605:6400:30:f174:42::]:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=503EB70C30120C72988B47087C720B582B6AB135 ("general SOCKS server failure")
Oct 26 17:40:30.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2a01:4f8:c012:da96::1]:1110 ID=<none> RSA_ID=8FB7B23A1D5DC1C0292C3EE6974FB4FD04CE4B3F ("general SOCKS server failure")
Oct 26 17:40:31.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2a01:4f8:c012:da96::1]:1110 ID=<none> RSA_ID=8FB7B23A1D5DC1C0292C3EE6974FB4FD04CE4B3F ("general SOCKS server failure")
Oct 26 17:40:32.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2a01:4f8:c012:da96::1]:1110 ID=<none> RSA_ID=8FB7B23A1D5DC1C0292C3EE6974FB4FD04CE4B3F ("general SOCKS server failure")
Oct 26 17:40:32.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2605:6400:30:f174:42::]:443 ID=<none> RSA_ID=503EB70C30120C72988B47087C720B582B6AB135 ("general SOCKS server failure")
Oct 26 17:40:33.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2a01:4f8:c012:da96::1]:1110 ID=<none> RSA_ID=8FB7B23A1D5DC1C0292C3EE6974FB4FD04CE4B3F ("general SOCKS server failure")
Oct 26 17:40:34.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2a01:4f8:c012:da96::1]:1110 ID=<none> RSA_ID=8FB7B23A1D5DC1C0292C3EE6974FB4FD04CE4B3F ("general SOCKS server failure")
Oct 26 17:40:36.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2a01:4f8:c012:da96::1]:1110 ID=<none> RSA_ID=8FB7B23A1D5DC1C0292C3EE6974FB4FD04CE4B3F ("general SOCKS server failure")
Oct 26 17:40:37.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 10% (conn_done): Connected to a relay
Oct 26 17:40:38.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 14% (handshake): Handshaking with a relay
Oct 26 17:40:40.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2a01:4f8:c012:da96::1]:1110 ID=<none> RSA_ID=8FB7B23A1D5DC1C0292C3EE6974FB4FD04CE4B3F ("general SOCKS server failure")
Oct 26 17:40:41.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2a01:4f8:c012:da96::1]:1110 ID=<none> RSA_ID=8FB7B23A1D5DC1C0292C3EE6974FB4FD04CE4B3F ("general SOCKS server failure")
Oct 26 17:40:42.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2a01:4f8:c012:da96::1]:1110 ID=<none> RSA_ID=8FB7B23A1D5DC1C0292C3EE6974FB4FD04CE4B3F ("general SOCKS server failure")
Oct 26 17:40:44.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2a01:4f8:c012:da96::1]:1110 ID=<none> RSA_ID=8FB7B23A1D5DC1C0292C3EE6974FB4FD04CE4B3F ("general SOCKS server failure")
Oct 26 17:40:45.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2a01:4f8:c012:da96::1]:1110 ID=<none> RSA_ID=8FB7B23A1D5DC1C0292C3EE6974FB4FD04CE4B3F ("general SOCKS server failure")
Oct 26 17:40:46.000 [warn] Proxy Client: unable to connect OR connection (handshaking (proxy)) with [2a01:4f8:c012:da96::1]:1110 ID=<none> RSA_ID=8FB7B23A1D5DC1C0292C3EE6974FB4FD04CE4B3F ("general SOCKS server failure")
^COct 26 17:40:46.000 [notice] Interrupt: exiting cleanly.


sudo systemctl stop tor
sudo apt remove tor
sudo apt-get install tor
sudo systemctl stop tor
sudo -u debian-tor tor

YES!!! Thor launched without errors!!! The joy did not last long. Now here's what:
Oct 26 16:49:55.000 [notice] Bootstrapped 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay
Oct 26 16:51:19.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay. (Connection refused; CONNECTREFUSED; count 10; recommendation warn; host 2390B303058F5EC1E1BEAAEECE3AAF2CF97B71F4 at 185.220.101.47:10047)
Oct 26 16:51:19.000 [warn] 9 connections have failed:
Oct 26 16:51:19.000 [warn]  9 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
Oct 26 16:51:19.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay. (Connection refused; CONNECTREFUSED; count 11; recommendation warn; host BD6A829255CB08E66FBE7D3748363586E46B3810 at 171.25.193.9:80)
Oct 26 16:51:19.000 [warn] 10 connections have failed:
Oct 26 16:51:19.000 [warn]  10 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)
Oct 26 16:51:22.000 [warn] Problem bootstrapping. Stuck at 5% (conn): Connecting to a relay. (Connection refused; CONNECTREFUSED; count 12; recommendation warn; host AA616315BA97729EA47DAD8718FA59269C7229E7 at 212.233.36.188:9001)
Oct 26 16:51:22.000 [warn] 11 connections have failed:
Oct 26 16:51:22.000 [warn]  11 connections died in state connect()ing with SSL state (No SSL object)

Who has any ideas? Please tell me what to do?
